# How to determine which SQL entries are missing after querying?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

Given the following database structure and using the EntityFramework.

[image]

Every five minutes, the 'phasecount' table gets records for each record in 'Phase'.

```
using (Entities db = new Entities())
{
    db.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    int numberofcontrollers = (from a in db.Junctions select a).Count();
    List<int> controllerids = (from b in db.Junctions select b.Id).ToList();

    var configuration = (from c in db.Configurations select c).First();

    DateTime laststamp = (from s in db.Stamps select s.Time).Max();
    DateTime firststamp = laststamp.AddMinutes(-1 * (CountIntervalsBefore - 1) * TimeSliceLength);

    var stamps = from s in db.Stamps.Include("PhaseCounts.Phase") where s.Time >= firststamp && s.Time <= laststamp orderby s.Id select s;
    // check consistency; number of stamps should equal timeslices*controllers

    if (stamps.Count() != CountIntervalsBefore * numberofcontrollers)
    {
         //counts are not available for all timeslices and controllers
         //do extended consistency check (and use dummy data?)
    }
}
```

I want to select for one hour each phasecount for all phases.

stamps normally equals 72, ie 12 5-minute slices * 6 junctions.

If it doesn't equal 72, how to determine which phases and which timestamps have missing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thoughts on a solution; this may not be the optimal search method but it should work.

Take the earliest timestamp in the group, and check that you do indeed have the correct number of records with that timestamp (from what you've said, I believe this is 6). From that you can tell if there are any missing from this set. Then look for the closest timestamp to the current one. If it's significantly more than about five minutes, you have a whole set missing. If it's around five minutes, check that you have the correct number of records with that timestamp, like with the first set. Repeat until either (total missing records + total found records = 72) or you run out of records. If you get to the end of the records and you still have some missing, then the earliest timestamp was not the first one, and you have a complete set missing there as well. At this point, either (total missing records + total found records = 72) or something has gone very wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to do it with some smart joins in the query, but until now I cannot find out how...